# How to use 'value' in textarea spring

Tags: html, spring, textarea

Hello i can't type **value**`="<c:out value='${medicines.description}'/>"` in textarea.

code:

```
<textarea name="inputDescription" value="<c:out value='${medicines.description}'/>" rows="5" 
    class="form-control"  placeholder="Description"  required autofocus /></textarea>
```

The error is **Undefined attribute name (value).** 
When im using `<input>` its works good. Can somebody explain me how to do that in textarea and select?

```
select name="inputDrugForm" id="inputDrug" >
                <option value="piece">Pills</option>
                <option value="ml.">Syrup</option>
                <option value="piece">Sachets</option>
                <option value="ml.">Spray</option>
                <option value="piece">Other</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside the textarea tag like this.

```
<textarea name="inputDescription" rows="5" 
    class="form-control"  placeholder="Description"  required autofocus>
<c:out value="${medicines.description}"/>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks its works in textarea now. But when i use this in `<select>` its not working. I was do that in this way `<option value="piece"><c:out value='${medicines.drugForm}'/></option>`, but this give me another option and i just want to replace the existing one. ~first post updated

Comment: What do you want to do in the select tag? Do you want to loop to display a list in the select tag?

Comment: Im using that in my add/edit form and potential user choosing what drug form he want to put in database. This select in post is for edit form so i want this select to read what drug form is in database(Pills, syrup , etc.)

Comment: If drugForm is a list. Imagine that it has the following properties (id, name). Then for the add form. You can do this.`<select>
    <c:forEach items="${medicines.drugForms}" var="drugForm">
        <option value="${drugForm.id}" >${drugForm.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>`. Now for the edit form.if you want to select the drugForm value. You must add this in option tag.`${drugForm.id== selectedDrugForm ? 'selected' : ''}`

Comment: So you have to loop to retrieve the list of drug forms. And it's on the option tag. For the case of the Edit form now to select the value of the selector that goes with the drug form, you must add a condition.